# Python variable propagation across WSGI workers

Tags: python, caching, wsgi

I have a Python Flask app with a counter that starts with the app. For every webpage served the counter is increased by 1. When counter = 10, a second_function shall be run.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

counter = 0


def second_function():
    print ('10 operations done')


@app.route('/')
def index ():
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 10:
        second_function()
        counter = 0
    return render_template('index.html')
```

It works well in my local computer, but not at the server because of WSGI.
Every WSGI worker counts the `counter` in a separated thread, while I need them counting together in a way that, when 10 webpages are served, the `second_function` is called, regardless of how many WSGI workers worked to serve the 10 webpages.

I already tried to store/read `counter` in a cache with Flask-Caching as well as ox_cache packages. While the implementation seems correct, they do not work correctly.

Comment: You're going to have to use something like redis, dragonflydb, memcached; or if you want something integrated into Python, the `shared_memory` module might be what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your comment. Following your suggestion I could implement it in redis, and is working fine.